# Python. how do i do split() from txt file?

Tags: python, list

```
 But soft what light through yonder window breaks
 It is the east and Juliet is the sun
 Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
 Who is already sick and pale with grief
```

From this file i have to 8.4 Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.
You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/romeo.txt

this is the frame, so i should follow this code only, and use append(), slpit() and sort() i should use them. or in other case it will show an error. because this assignment from coursera.com

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
print(line.rstrip())
```

and the output should as following:

```
      ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 
      'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 
      'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please specify your problem, what you have tried and how your output differs from the expected output. Right now we have only some input, expected output and five lines of code that are not even valid python.

Comment: You need to split `line` on space. Then, for each word in the resulting array, check if it is in `lst.` If not, add it.

Answer (score 0):

To read a text file you must open it first:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as in_txt:
    values = in_txt
    l=[]
    for a in values:
        l.extend(a.split())
    print(l)
```

Use `with` to make sure your file is closed. `'r'` for read-only mode.
`extend` will add elements from a list, in this case `a` to an existing list, `l`.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = set()
with open('path/to/romeo.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        words.update(set(line.split()))

words = sorted(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')

# Split by whitespace
arr = data.split(' ')

#Filter all empty elements and linebreaks
arr = [elem for elem in arr if elem != '' and elem != '\r\n']

# Only unique elements
my_list = list(set(arr))

# Print sorted array
print(sorted(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `set`s in python is better than list in your example.

sets are iterables that does not have duplicate members.

```
# open, read and split words
myfile_words = open('romeo.txt').read().split()

# create a set to save words
list_of_words = set()

# for loop for each word in word list and it to our word list
for word in myfile_words:
    list_of_words.add(word)

# close file after use, otherwise it will stay in memory
myfile_words.close()

# create a sorted list of our words
list_of_words = sorted(list(list_of_words))
```